# finding sum of three columns obtained from left join of three tables

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata

I have 4 tables:

```
accounts_info
----------------------------------------------
user_id | user_type | user_page | device_type 


hostel_billing (can have duplicate user_id)
-------------------------
user_id | billing_charges

academic_billing (can have duplicate user_id)
-------------------------
user_id | academic_charges

misc_billing (can have duplicate user_id)
-------------------------
user_id | misc_charges
```

I want to create a new table pulling out data from above 4 tables:

```
user_expenses 
---------------------------------------------------------------
user_id | user_type | user_page | device_type | total_charges
```

total_charges will be sum of `total_charges = misc_charges + academic_charges + billing_charges`.
calculating total charges is something i am unable to figure out.

so far i have been able to get sum of misc_charges, academic_charges and billing_charges
for each user_id with this query but could not figure out how to sum up three columns hostel_charges, misc_charges, and academic_charges obtained from joining hostel_billing, misc_billing and academic_billing respectively:

```
with user_info as (
select 
   user_id, user_type, user_page, device_type 
from accounts_info 
),

academics as (
select user_id, sum(academic_charges) as academic from academic_billing group by 1
),

hostels as (
select user_id, sum(hostel_charges) as hostel from hostel_billing group by 1
),

misc as (
select user_id, sum(misc_charges) as misc from misc_billing group by 1
)

select 
     ui.user_id, 
     ui.user_page, 
     ui.user_type, 
     ui.device_type, 
     sum(a.academic_charges),
     sum(m.misc_charges), 
     sum(h.hostel_charges)
from user info ui left join misc m on ui.user_id=m.user_id
left join hostels h on ui.user_id=h.user_id
left join academics a on ui.user_id=a.user_id
group by 1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be pretty straightforward, can you try:

```
with user_info as (
select 
   user_id, user_type, user_page, device_type 
from accounts_info 
),

academics as (
select user_id, sum(academic_charges) as academic from academic_billing group by 1
),

hostels as (
select user_id, sum(hostel_charges) as hostel from hostel_billing group by 1
),

misc as (
select user_id, sum(misc_charges) as misc from misc_billing group by 1
)

select 
     ui.user_id, 
     ui.user_page, 
     ui.user_type, 
     ui.device_type, 
     sum(a.academic_charges) + sum(m.misc_charges) + sum(h.hostel_charges) as total_charges
from user info ui left join misc m on ui.user_id=m.user_id
left join hostels h on ui.user_id=h.user_id
left join academics a on ui.user_id=a.user_id
group by 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: thanks, that works, should have figured it out though!!

Comment: @vijayshanker . . . I don't think this returns the correct answer for users who do not have all three billing types.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... can you explain a little more

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one row `user_id` in `accounts_info, you do not need the outer aggregation.  All the aggregation queries return one row per`user_id`, so there is no need to re-aggregate at that level.  It just slows down the query.

So:

```
with user_info as (
      select user_id, user_type, user_page, device_type 
      from accounts_info 
     ),
     academics as (
      select user_id, sum(academic_charges) as academic 
      from academic_billing
      group by 1
     ),
     hostels as (
      select user_id, sum(hostel_charges) as hostel
      from hostel_billing
      group by 1
     ),
     misc as (
      select user_id, sum(misc_charges) as misc
      from misc_billing
      group by 1
     )
select ui.user_id, ui.user_page, ui.user_type, ui.device_type, 
       a.academic_charges, m.misc_charges, h.hostel_charges,
       (coalesce(a.academic_charges, 0) +
        coalesce(m.misc_charges, 0) +
        coalesce(h.hostel_charges, 0)
       ) as total
from user_info ui left join
     misc m
     on ui.user_id = m.user_id left join
     hostels h
     on ui.user_id = h.user_id left join
     academics a
     on ui.user_id = a.user_id;
```

The `coalesce()` is very important.  Otherwise, the `sum()` will not be correct for users who do not have all three billing types.

Comment: use of coalesce i understand, but why did you left the SUM() and group by here

Comment: can you explain about not needing outer aggregation